# Item could not be updated: Gateway rejected: fraud

Tags: heroku

To add my credit card to heroku, I supplied all details but when I tried to save details, it gave me this error:

```
Item could not be updated: 
Gateway rejected: fraud
```

Please what do I do???...thanks

Answer (score 2):

It should probably be an issue with the credit card, this error usually happens when the card is blocked. If you're sure your credit card works and the information you are providing is correct, the best thing to do is contacting Heroku support as only they are able to check what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

You may receive the error message **Gateway Declined: Fraud** if you have entered your card multiple times in close succession. This is a temporary lock-out from entering your card again, but will go away after a few hours.